# Kestrel MaxRequestBodySize uploading file over the limit

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I did encounter a wierd problem with kestrel. I am not able to upload the multiple files which exceed the kestrel's MaxRequestBodySize.

The expected behaviour is to throw the *BadHttpRequestException* when I am trying to reader *this.Request.Form.Files.GetFiles()*. I do expect to recieve request to controller action only once.

What is happening is that the upload action is hit a few time and browser with message "conection lost". I did not find a patter on how mamy times the action is called.

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var files = this.Request.Form.Files.GetFiles("files");
        files.Select(async file => await this.SaveFile(file))
        return this.RedirectToAction(nameof(VueController.FilesList),"Vue");
    }
    catch (BadHttpRequestException exp)
    {
        return new string[]
        {
            exp.Message
        };
    }
}
```

view:

```
<form method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="/api/v1/files/upload"
          novalidate="novalidate">
      <input type="file"
             name="files"
             multiple="multiple"
             required="required"
             accept=""
             capture="capture" />
    </form>
```

asp.net core logs:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
> Connection id "0HLDB9K94VV9M" bad request data: "Request body too large."
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
> Request body too large.   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowRequestRejected(RequestRejectionReason
> reason)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStart()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.d__24.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> Request finished in 7618.6319ms 413

**Edited**
I am aware that I can disabled the limit but it is not possible in this case.

Comment: Check this announcement https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267 ^^

Comment: You can also override it per request as noted in the linked announcement, via `[RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must configure two things:

In your Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebhost(string[] args) => 
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .UseKestrel(options => {
           options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; // or a given limit
      })
     .Build();
```

In your Startup.cs in the ConfigureService method

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue); // or other given limit
```

Also change your controller endpoint to use `[FromForm]`

```
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)... // name must be same as name attribute of your multipart form
```

Now ASP.NET Core will do the work and inject the files from the form as sequence.

**Edit:**

I created an example that can be cloned from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/alsami/example-fileupload-aspnet-core.git
cd example-fileupload-aspnet-core
dotnet restore
dotnet run --project src/file-upload-api/file-upload-api.csproj
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:5000/index.html and try uploading huge files.

Comment: Did you also configure the form options? If so, what's the error now? Please update the OP.

Comment: I did not configure the options in services, let me try this.

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look and try changing your controller endpoint as suggested.

Comment: I have added configuratiob for FromOption but is still does not work. The behaviour is exactly the same.

Comment: Updated the answer with an executable sample.

Comment: Must be related to your code. Please use the example project I provided and compare it to your code and do the adjustment as I said.

Comment: The solution you have proposed is working, the key was to set the value of Kestrel limit to null and not to have it empty.

Comment: Yeah, is what I wrote in the first place anyway.

Comment: There is another issue. When I set tu kester limit to null and the MultipartBodyLengthLimit  is higher than 30Mb( which is default Kestrel body limit) there is no limit to a file size at all.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267) the max limit can be override globally for all actions or specifically for a single one using the `[RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]` (or `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` to disable the limit) on a given action.

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Files Upload Action should be like that;

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(1000 * 1024 * 1024)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1000 * 1024 * 1024)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IList<IFormFile> files)
```