# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upload a 100MB film to my ASP.NET Core application.

I've set this attribute on my action:

```cs
[RequestSizeLimit(1_000_000_000)]
```

And I also changed my `Web.config` file to include:

```xml
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <!-- This will handle requests up to 700MB (CD700) -->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="737280000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

In other words, I've told IIS to allow files up to 700MBs and I've also told ASP.NET Core to allow files of near 1GB.

But I still get that error. And I can't find the answer. Any ideas?

P.S: Using these configurations, I could pass the 30MB default size. I can upload files of 50 or 70 Mega Bytes.

Comment: See [Kestrel MaxRequestBodySize uploading file over the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037706/kestler-maxrequestbodysize-uploading-file-over-the-limit)

Answer (score 40):

I think you just need: [DisableRequestSizeLimit]

below is a solution that worked for me to upload Zip files with additional form data to an API running .Net Core 3

```cs
// MultipartBodyLengthLimit  was needed for zip files with form data.
// [DisableRequestSizeLimit] works for the KESTREL server, but not IIS server 
// for IIS: webconfig... <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102428800" />
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)] 
[DisableRequestSizeLimit] 
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")] // for Zip files with form data
[HttpPost("MyCustomRoute")]
public IActionResult UploadZippedFiles([FromForm] MyCustomFormObject formData)
{ }
```

Comment: I was close give up but your solution works like a charm! I also found this link https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20369#issuecomment-607057822

Comment: This worked for me on a Brand new .Net Core 3.1 MVC app. other solutions, like updating the `ConfigureServices` on `Startup.cs` and @YorJaggy's url (which i found before this site), didn't work.

Comment: I'm suspicious of your solution. It seems to work like a charm. But that's what worries me... Why do the other poor schmucks keep fighting with settings on IIS etc. if there's this simple solution? I fear that it opens a can of worms without me realizing it. What's the downside of it?

Answer (score 14):

For me (**Asp.net core 3.1**) the solution was to add these lines in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`:

```cs
    // 200 MB
    const int maxRequestLimit = 209715200;
    // If using IIS
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = maxRequestLimit;
    });
    // If using Kestrel
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = maxRequestLimit;
    });
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
    {
        x.ValueLengthLimit = maxRequestLimit;
        x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = maxRequestLimit;
        x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = maxRequestLimit;
    });
```

and editing `web.config`:

```xml
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 7):

> NOTE: This is issue I faced when I migrated my application from
> asp.net core 2.1 to 3.0

To fix this in asp.net core 3.0 I have changed my program.cs to modify maximum request body size like below.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
       return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 737280000;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

I mean I have just added `ConfigureKestrel` part and added an attribute above my action method `[RequestSizeLimit(737280000)]` like below

```cs
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(737280000)]
[Route("SomeRoute")]
public async Task<ViewResult> MyActionMethodAsync([FromForm]MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
   //Some code
   return View();
}
```

And my application started behaving correctly again without throwing `BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large`

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0#kestrel-maximum-request-body-size

Answer (score 4):

I was using `web.config` to configure this (while our api is hosted in IIS):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But now we are moving our api to linux containers and using Kestrel. Then I configured it like this:

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder
    .ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
    {
        serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 157286400;
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
})
```

157286400 = 150mb;

Answer (score 1):

Azure functions have a hard-coded limit of 100MB: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5854

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share what worked for me. I have a .NET 6 MVC application which will receive data at an endpoint.

When the data that is pushed to this endpoint exceeded the default size of the request body of the `httpContextObject`, the following excpetion was logged.

[image]

The fix, as mentioned above, is to increase the size of the request body of the HTTP Request that the application received. This can be done in several ways and has been detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#maximum-request-body-size). The fixed that worked for me was

```
// Configures MaxRequestBodySize for all requests:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 100_000_000;
});
```

This will set the MaxRequestBodySize for all requests that this application will receive to apporximately 95.3674 Megabyte. We can also set this to any size we want. E.g. setting this value to `int.MaxValue` will set this to 2,147,483,647 bytes (= 2,048.0 Megabytes) .

As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestbodysize?view=aspnetcore-7.0) **we can set the size of the request body to unlimted** when this property is set to null